# How to enter data for StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed example so timestamps are different (than from 1970)?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I run the Structured Streaming demo named [StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.scala),
I am confuse why the timestamp is "1970-01-19 13:28:00".
How should I input the example data ？

Input:

```
[i@15:44:48]~$ nc -lk 9999
(123 123,2017-10-13 10:28.24.0)
123
345
```

Output：

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----+
|window                                    |word          |count|
+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----+
|[1970-01-19 13:27:00, 1970-01-19 13:28:00]|123,2017-10-13|1    |
|[1970-01-19 13:27:00, 1970-01-19 13:28:00]|123           |1    |
|[1970-01-19 13:27:00, 1970-01-19 13:28:00]|(123          |1    |
|[1970-01-19 13:27:00, 1970-01-19 13:28:00]|10:28.24.0)   |1    |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: The code uses [.option("includeTimestamp", true)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.scala#L80) so it should give you proper timestamps. How do you execute the example?

Comment: What's the local time?

Answer (score 0):

From the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.scala#L76-L81):

```
val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", host)
  .option("port", port)
  .option("includeTimestamp", true)
  .load()
```

That says it's not you to enter the timestamps but the `socket` data source does this for you.

Whatever you type is considered a text line that is [split into words](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.scala#L85) using `" "` (space) word separator.

That says there has to be something incorrect in the socket data source itself not the example or whatever you type.

It is also possible that the operating system is misconfigured with an incorrect date (!)

Comment: I used Mac to test this demo, also, I packaged the code and put it in a Centos Server. Both method get the same result. I got wrong timestamp. How could I figure it out whether the operating system is misconfigured with an incorrect date or not

Comment: Just do `date` and see what you get.

Comment: [i@19:36:54]~$ date
2019年11月28日 星期四 19时36分55秒 CST